# Why am I getting undefined while trying to filter the movie release_date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

[image]

This is the favorites state which contains the movie release_date.

I'm trying to put filter the release_date into the dates state as shown here:

```
sortMovies= () => {
    let releases = this.state.favorites.filter(this.favorites.release_date)
    this.setState({
      dates: releases,
    });
    console.log(this.state.dates);
}
```

I put this function in a button onClick and when I press it I get :

[image]

How do I filter out all the release_date in the favorites state and add it to the dates state?

Answer (score 5):

`filter` will filter out each entry in the array that returns a truthy value. You are trying to extract the `release_date` of each favorite, so `map` would be more suited for this:

```
let releases = this.state.favorites.map(favorite => favorite.release_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `Array.prototype.filter()` expects the first parameter to be a 
[function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

You are trying to use `this.favorites.release_date` which is not a function and it is undefined because `this.favorites` is an array.

Instead use a callback function which will test each element of the array and will return true in the case of match, otherwise false.

```
const releases = this.state.favorites.filter(movie => !!movie.release_date)
```